# Designing a Linux char device driver so multiple processes can read

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I notice that for serial devices, e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`, multiple processes can open the device but only one process gets the bytes (whichever reads them first).

However, for the Linux input API, e.g. `/dev/input/event0`, multiple processes can open the device, and all of the processes are able to read the input events.

My current goal:

I'd like to write a driver for several multi-position switches (e.g. like a slider switch with 3 or 4 possible positions), where apps can get a notification of any switch position changes. Ideally I'd like to use the Linux input API, however it seems that the Linux input API has no support for the concept of multi-position switches. So I'm looking at making a custom driver with similar capabilities to the Linux input API.

Two questions:

- From a driver design point-of-view, why is there that difference in behaviour between Linux input API and Linux serial devices? I reckon it could be useful for multiple processes to all be able to open one serial port and all listen to incoming bytes.
- What is a good way to write a Linux character device driver so that it's like the Linux input API, so multiple processes can open the device and read all the data?

Comment: Read only, probably, yes you can modify driver, but for write? Serial lines usually are not used for read only, but events. This I suspect main conceptual difference.

Comment: You may consider doing this in userspace: The other processes can connect to a daemon that multiplexes data from the serial port through FIFOs. You probably can write this in 50 lines of C code (even less with something like Python). I may try to write an example if you find this an acceptable solution for your problem.

Comment: "however it seems that the Linux input API has no support for the concept of multi-position switches." - you can translate this to Joystick API as axis (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/joystick-api.txt `JS_EVENT_AXIS`; several axis per joystick are allowed; every position will give some fixed value, for example -100; 0; +100), but I have no information about multiple process usage of joystcik

Answer (score 9):

The distinction is partly historical and partly due to the different expectation models.

- The `event` subsystem is designed for unidirectional notification of simple events from multiple writers into the system with very little (or no) configuration options.
- The `tty` subsystem is intended for bidirectional end-to-end communication of potentially large amounts of data and provides a reasonably flexible (albeit fairly baroque) configuration mechanism.

Historically, the `tty` subsystem was the main mechanism of communicating with the system: you plug your "teletype" into a serial port and bits went in and out.  Different teletypes from different vendors used different protocols and thus the `termios` interface was born.  To make the system perform well in a multi-user context, buffering was added in the kernel (and made configurable).  The expectation model of the `tty` subsystem is that of a point-to-point link between moderately intelligent endpoints who will agree on what the data passing between them will look like.

While there are circumstances where "single writer, multiple readers" would make sense in the `tty` subsystem (GPS receiver connected to a serial port, continually reporting its position, for instance), that's not the main purpose of the system.  But you can easily accomplish this "multiple readers" in userspace.

The `event` system on the other hand, is basically an interrupt mechanism intended for things like mice and keyboards.  Unlike teletypes, input devices are unidirectional and provide little or no control over the data they produce.  There is also little point in buffering the data.  Nobody is going to be interested in where the mouse moved ten minutes ago.

I hope that answers your first question.

For your second question: "it depends".  What do you want to accomplish?  And what is the "longevity" of the data?  You also have to ask yourself whether it makes sense to put the complexity in the kernel or if it wouldn't be better to put it in userspace.

Getting data out to multiple readers isn't particularly difficult.  You could create a receive buffer per reader and fill each of them as the data comes in.  Things get a little more interesting if the data comes in faster than the readers can consume it, but even that is mostly a solved problem.  Look at the network stack for inspiration!

If your device is simple and just produces events, maybe you just want to be an input driver?

Your second question is a lot more difficult to answer without knowing more about what you want to accomplish.

Update after you added your specific goal:

When I do position switches, I usually just create a character device and implement `poll` and `read`.  If you want to be fancy and have a lot of switches, you could do `mmap` but I wouldn't bother.

Userspace just opens your `/dev/foo` and reads the current state and starts polling.  When your switches change state, you just wake up the readers and they they'll read again.  All your readers will wake up, they'll all read the new state and everyone will be happy.

Be careful to only wake up readers when your switches are 'settled'.  Many position switches are very noisy and they'll bounce around a fair bit.

In other words: I would ignore the input system altogether for this.  As you surmise, position switches are not really "inputs".

Answer (score 4):

How a character device handles these kinds of semantics is completely up to the driver to define and implement.

It would certainly be possible, for example, to implement a driver for a serial device that will deliver all read data to every process that has the character driver open. And it would also be possible to implement an input device driver that delivers events to only one process, whichever one is queued up to receive the latest event. It's all a matter of coding the appropriate implementation.

The difference is that it all comes down to a simple question: "what makes sense". For a serial device, it's been decided that it makes more sense to handle any read data by a single process. For an input device, it's been decided that it makes more sense to deliver all input events to every process that has the input device open. It would be reasonable to expect that, for example, one process might only care about a particular input event, say pointer button #3 pressed, while another process wants to process all pointer motion events. So, in this situation, it might make more sense to distribute all input events to all concerned parties.

I am ignoring some side issues, for simplicity, like in the situation of serial data being delivered to all reading processes what should happen when one of them stops reading from the device. That's also something that would be factored in, when deciding how to implement the semantics of a particular device.

Answer (score 3):

> What is a good way to write a Linux character device driver so that it's like the Linux input API, so multiple processes can open the device and read all the data?

See the `.open` member of `struct file_operations` for the char device. Whenever userspace opens the device, then the `.open` function is called. It can add the open file to a list of open files for the device (and then `.release` removes it).

The char device data struct should most likely use a kernel `struct list_head` to keep a list of open files:

```
struct my_dev_data {
    ...
    struct cdev         cdev;
    struct list_head    file_open_list;
    ...
}
```

Data for each file:

```
struct file_data {
    struct my_dev_data        *dev_data;
    struct list_head          file_open_list;
    ...
}
```

In the `.open` function, add the open file to `dev_data->file_open_list` (use a mutex to protect these operations as needed):

```
static int my_dev_input_open(struct inode * inode, struct file * filp)
{
    struct my_dev_data  *dev_data;

    dev_data = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct my_dev_data, cdev);
    ...
    /* Allocate memory for file data and channel data */
    file_data = devm_kzalloc(&dev_data->pdev->dev,
        sizeof(struct file_data), GFP_KERNEL);
    ...
    /* Add open file data to list */
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&file_data->file_open_list);
    list_add(&file_data->file_open_list, &dev_data->file_open_list);
    ...
    file_data->dev_data = dev_data;
    filp->private_data = file_data;
}
```

The `.release` function should remove the open file from `dev_data->file_open_list`, and release the memory of `file_data`.

Now that the `.open` and `.release` functions maintain the list of open files, it is possible for all open files to read data. Two possible strategies:

1. A separate read buffer for each open file. When data is received, it is copied into the buffers of all open files.
2. A single read buffer for the device, but a separate read *pointer* for each open file. Data can be freed from the buffer once it has been read through all open files.

Answer (score 1):

#### Serial to input/event

You could try to look into *serial mouse driver* source code.

This seem to be what you're searching for: from a `TTYSx` build a `input/event` device.

#### Simplier: creating a ***server***, instead of a ***driver***.

Historically, the 1st character device I remember is *`/dev/lp0`*.

To be able to write on it from many source, without overlap or other conflict,
a *`LPR`* server was wrotten.

To share a device, you have to

1. open this device in exclusive (rw) mode.
2. Create a socket (un*x or TCP) to listen on
3. redirect request from socket's clients to the device and maybe
4. store device status (from reading device's answers)
5. send device status to socket's clients when required.